# How can I capture text input dialogue in a tex input popup box on iPhone? i.e. name and email

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

In my app, when the user taps a button a number will decrease until it hits zero. When the number hits zero I want to display an input popup box for the user to put their name and email. I then want to be able to capture this information, as the developer, so that I can then be able to contact the user of my app. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

A quick suggestion:

The decrease of Number you can do in the IBAction method of that button where you getting call on every hit on button. You can keep the count in a variable and keep on change the text of label accordingly.

When Count becomes 0, you can get the help from this library to show a popUp view for input.

[PopUp  from CocoaControls -- Click here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/popup)

You may need to customize the library according to your requirement.

Happy coding.